# What quote does the image represent?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

The above image represents a variation of an extremely famous idiom (that is often inscribed on a medium which would make the message self-contradictory), can you decipher it? (Again, as always, I created it by myself.)

---

Hint:

> Pay attention to the texture of the shapes, what does it remind you?

> Try to rearrange the shapes and you should get a common English word with seven letters.

---

I guess this thing is a little bit hard, so I will give you one more hint, yes, the word is nothing, notice what state the word is in?

You can solve the puzzle by Google searching the idiom with the word that describes the state, I have double checked it.

Decode this simple message (base36):

> 1c 1c 19 2t 3a 2p 32

You should get a string seven characters long, with two numbers and four letters, then it takes some lateral thinking (or a simple Google searching) to get the exact word you need.

You don't need to decode the message if your vocabulary is big enough.

Comment: rot13(Vs vg jnf abg n dhbgr ohg na vqvbz, 'Abguvat vf jevggra va fgbar' jbhyq xvaq bs svg)

Comment: @LukasRotter You got the first part right, there is a second part, that is why the shapes are broken.

Comment: @LukasRotter or rot13(Abguvat va gur jbeyq vf jbegu univat be jbegu qbvat hayrff vg zrnaf rssbeg, cnva, qvssvphygl)

Comment: The texture looks like rot13(yrngure) to me, but I can't think of any quotes that would work with that.

Comment: What? Are leathers grey? Rhinoceros leather?

Comment: Well, [yeah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye). But that aside, the base 36 encoding can be deciphered different ways, encoding in such a base, to remove any ambiguity, would requires spaces between each character, otherwise you'll end up with the current decoding of the hint, which is rot13(O O SZ Q P 6)

Comment: "Ceci n'est pas une quote."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess it could be

> [Nothing is written stone, child. Even if it were, the stones can be shattered](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/331012-nothing-is-written-stone-child-even-if-it-were-the)

Because

> Pieces can be rearranged to "Nothing"
> [image]
>  Texture looks a bit like stone to me, so we have the idiom "Nothing is written in stone", which is self-contradictory when written in stone :)
>  The pieces are broken, or "shattered". The base36 decodes to `00-evan`, which leads to the "**shattered** pixel dungeon" github page.
>  Combining those and googling gave me the quote by Melanie Rawn above.