# What concept does the image symbolize?

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

Well this is much more obscure than the previous one, but the puzzle is still very simple if you think about it a little bit more.

I will give you four images, each of them are connected to the concept, a central theme, your task is to identify the theme, and explain the meaning of each image.

The answer is one common English word seven letters long.

[image]

---

Not a hint:

The images were meant to depict (left-right, top-down):

- Torn spiderweb
- Cross roads
- Ocean-sky horizon
- Icarus falling

---

OK, seems this puzzle is a little bit more difficult than I thought it to be. So I will give you exactly one more hint, and after that there will be no more hints.

> The word starts with f, not an F-word though!

Comment: The clues are all present in the pictures, and they are sufficient for the purpose.

Comment: The answer is related to [this question's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/116615/79040) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be

> freedom?

> The spiderweb is torn, so whatever was trapped inside is now free.

> The crossroad represents freedom of choice.

> The open sea is commonly associated with freedom.

> Icarus wings bring to mind the saying "free as a bird".

Comment: It is freedom, but you need to explain the last image, I will give you a hint: what do Icarus's wings look like?

Comment: I added an explanation for the Icarus picture in my answer. Be careful, your comment is spoiling the answer.